# Elasticsearch : write aggregate query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document, pageTransition in ElasticSearch which stores the pages visited by user. It has fromPageId, toPageId, created(time of visit) etc..
The single record looks like below when user goes from page 183 to page 184

```
"clientId": 0,
"fromUrl": "http://ats.survale.com/Apply/AdditionalInfo.aspx",
"toUrl": "http://ats.survale.com/Apply/ConfirmInfo.aspx",
"fromPageId": "183",
"toPageId": "184",
"created": "2016-02-29T18:22:49.509Z"
```

Now I want a count of all pageTransitions in last 7 days. I mean 182-183: 12 , 183-184: 13 and so on. Along with it I also want the average time user spent on each page. Is it possible using aggregation?

Answer (score 0):

To get the count of page transitions over the lats 7 days, you can use this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "created": {
            "gt": "now-7d"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "transitions": {
      "terms": {
        "script": "[doc.fromPageId.value, doc.toPageId].join('-')"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In order for this to work you need to make sure that [dynamic scripting is enabled](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting)

Comment: does this need script to be enabled in elasticsearch?

Comment: without script how can we do? and also can it return an array of all the timestamps so I can manually compute the average time..

Comment: You can achieve this without scripting, if you also index a new field called `"fromToPageId": "183-184"`

Comment: is it better to store time spent on each page as a separate field , rather than we trying to compute it from created time. then using avg aggregate to find average time spent.

Comment: Of course, if you have that information at indexing time, you should definitely store it as well, it will make the query much faster at search time.